# How can the Delphi XE datasnap server be configured for HTTPS

Tags: delphi, rest, https, datasnap

How can a Datasnap REST server (running as a service on Windows) be configured to process https calls in Delphi XE? Are there any good examples around?
Delphi XE2 upwards appears to have additional components - does this mean that XE can't do it?

Answer (score 2):

According to the "What's New" in Delphi XE2:

> Support for HTTPS in DataSnap Server Wizard and DataSnap WebBroker Application Wizard. This is great because:
>   Now the server does not have to be running in IIS to have HTTPS support (as it was before).
>   You can avoid the complexity and the overhead of IIS.

Comment: That sounds like the answer is 'not in Delphi XE' - Anyone have any bright ideas without investing in a Delphi upgrade? (and the subsequent 'fun' of migrating code!)

Answer (score 0):

Does the Datasnap server run as a stand-alone process or service (not in IIS)? In this case I would place the DataSnap server behind a reverse http proxy, for example the Apache HTTP server. Revers proxy configuration can be done with a few lines.

(using a reverse proxy in front of the Delphi server also has other advantages)